# MSHTML: IHtmlDocument - how to subscribe to custom javascript events

Tags: javascript, c#, internet-explorer, mshtml

I'm writing an extension for IE in c#.
I've got a `IWebBrowser2` object called `browser` and from it I can get an `IHtmlDocument2` object like this:

`var document = browser.Document as IHTMLDocument2;`

Now I need to react on a javascript event which is fired by this code:

```
var event = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
event.initEvent('MyCustomEvent', true, false);
someElement.dispatchEvent(event);
```

I see that I can use `click`, `mouseleave` and other properties from [HTMLDocumentEvents2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa769764%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) interface to subscribe to typical events, but I can't find something like `OnCustomEvent` or `HtmlEvents['MyCustomEvent'] += ...` , etc.

It was easy to implement this functionality in firefox add-on, but with IE it's a pain...
Is this even possible?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use attachEvent to listen to the event. I've tested similar code work for onmessage event(doesn't have a specific event handler) in IE 10.

```
[ComVisible(true)]
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDispatch)]
public class EventListener
{
    [DispId(0)]
    public void handler(IHTMLEventObj evt) 
    {
        MessageBox.Show("message received");
    }
}

void AddEventListener()
{
    var evtListener = new EventListener();
    var window = ((IHTMLDocument2)browser.Document).parentWindow as IHTMLWindow3;
    window.attachEvent("MyCustomEvent", evtListener); //or try onMyCustomEvent
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It looks like there are a few different ways you can approach the problem.

Here are a couple of links that look relevant:

- [Handling HTML element events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/bb508508(v=vs.94).aspx#Sink) (MSDN)
- [Web browser control: How to capture document events?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9110388/web-browser-control-how-to-capture-document-events) (SO)

Hope this helps...

-- Lance