# Create VB program to watch a website in Internet Explorer

Tags: vb.net

Thanks for taking the time to assist me.

At work we use a 3rd party online chat system using internet explorer. Basically what happens is we initially follow a link, login, a pop up window comes up with the chat control page where we would see a notification for a new chat

The issue we have is no sound plays, and it's very easy to miss a chat.

In theory could I easily learn in VB how to watch that specific window of Internet Explorer for a change, then play a sound when a change in that window occurs until acknowledged?

Comment: One hint is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9110388/web-browser-control-how-to-capture-document-events.  Though its in c# but useful to see changes in windows

Comment: @Remankingdom thank you for your help!

Comment: Is it Useful to you  ?